# Asp.Net Web Application authentication using WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I have a WCF service which is repsonsible for authenticating users . Unlike WCF Authentication Services , I want all authentication (including the ones from a asp.net web application) to happen at the WCF service layer .

Now,  my query , should I be defining  membership providers for authentication at the web application tier.Say , for eg, I define a custom WCF memebership provider that calls the WCF service to carry out authentication. 
or If the application uses forms authentication for authenticating users against a active directory , I would use a Active directory membership provider at the Web Tier.

As per my logic , since I want the WCF service to be repsonsible for authenticating users from different applications , I would define the membership providers at the service layer .

However , there are difference in opinion as to which layer is responsible for implementing the membership provider .

Thansk & Regards
Girija

Answer (score 0):

You can't (and should not) perform, let's say, Windows authentication for asp.net application in WCF. Nor should you make your service responsible for determining *which* authentication uses asp.net.

In short, you should *define* your authentication mechanism at application level (although you can *implement* it at any level you want).

And by the way I would recommend you using already established federation protocols (i.e., WIF) for handling authenticaion between several applications.

Comment: If I use WIF , isn't it that all authentication calls (including windows authentication for asp.net) gets directed to federation provider & then the federation provider decides as to which identity provider to use to authenticate the user. So, in my application in the absence of WIF , won't it be the service that is playing the role of a federation provider .

Comment: It will be playing that role, but why invent your own protocol for doing that?